# jQuery find img tag and get SRC from it

Tags: jquery

I have this js code:

```
var imgJPG = jQuery('img[src$=".jpg"]', '<div>' + 
             fullCode + '</div>').attr('href');
```

However, it does not seem to pick up the src of the image?? fullCode is the HTML source code.

The HTML:

```
<strong><span style="font-size: small;">
<img class="alignleft" title="ASHE" src="http://www.website.org/san-logo.jpg" 
alt="" width="198" height="192" />Design (D) is an at the Annual Conference, 
held July 15-18, 2012 in San, Florida.</span></strong>
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: You do .attr('href') while you are looking for .attr('src') ?

Comment: You are correct, Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're retreveing 'href' instead of 'src'

```
var imgJPG = jQuery('img[src$=".jpg"]', '<div>' + fullCode + '</div>').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery document does not inidicate that it supports the case you're using.  The second argument to `jQuery()` is a context argument which (per the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)) can be a DOM element, a document or a jQuery object.  jQuery does not say that it supports it as a string of HTML.

You should first need to load that string into a jQuery object so that it gets turned into actual DOM elements like this:

```
var imgJPG = jQuery('img[src$=".jpg"]', jQuery('<div>' + 
         fullCode + '</div>')).attr('src');
```

In addition, if you want the `.src` attribute, that's the attribute you should retrieve instead of `.href`.

Comment: It works fine as-is though right now doing it the way in the OP.

Comment: @StealthRT - As it turns out, jQuery will handle a string for the context, but it is NOT documented to do so.  If you do it this way, you are relying on undocumented features that could possibly change in the future.  It would be safer to wrap that second argument in a jQuery call itself and follow the documented interface.

Answer (score 1):

Is it that you are looking for `href` when the actual attribute you need is `src`?

Comment: Src and yep just saw that! Thanks Paddy

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var imgJPG = jQuery('<div>' + fullCode + '</div>').find('img[src$=".jpg"]').attr('src');
```

That creates a `div` element, with the included html, and then performs a `find` to get the image.  Finally, get the image `src`.